# How to override a javascript IIFE returned method in an object?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I have one IIFE content which looks like this:

```
var A = (function() { 
     var method1 = function() { 
         alert("PARENT METHOD");
     }
     var method2 = function() {
        method1();
     }

    return {
        method1: method1,
        method2: method2
    }
})();
```

I want to override this method1 in another javascript object in a way when this method2 executes then it will call the overriden method1, not this original method1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because of the closure and method2 directly referencing the method1 variable you aren't going to be able to change the what method2 is calling. Give me a quick minute and I will throw together a quick example of how you could accomplish this.

Comment: @AdamH I can change the basic structure of these objects but it has to follow the coding standards too. Thanks anyway.

Comment: take a look at the answer I just added, this is how you would accomplish this. Coding standards change from shop to shop so which coding standards are you attempting to adhere to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use prototype in order to accomplish this the way you would like. Take a look at the example below.

```js
var A = (function() { 
   var api = function(){}
     
     api.prototype.method1 = function() { 
         console.log("PARENT METHOD");
     }
     
     api.prototype.method2 = function() {
        this.method1();
     }

    return new api();
})();

A.method2();
A.method1 = function() { console.log('child method');}
A.method2();
```

Comment: @suchit glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking then you can just set the value of `method2` (in your API object) to the overridden method (`B`'s `method1` in this example). Since `A` is created using IIFE, the object containing the overridden method must be declared before `A` or you will wind up with a reference error.

```js
var B = {
  method1: function() {
    console.log('This is method2 in B!');
  }
}

var A = (function() {
  var method1 = function() {
    alert("PARENT METHOD");
  }
  var method2 = function() {
    method1();
  }

  return {
    method1: method1,
    method2: B.method1
  }
})();


//call A.method2
A.method2();
```